# Regarding direction-dependent quantities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

We observationally determine whether a quantity can be a vector or not. For example, we chose force and momentum to be vectors to due to the fact that inertia depends on direction.

Then it seems like angle $\theta$ (in radians) should be scalar but we chose theta to be a vector perpendicular to the plane, just so that angular velocity $\omega$ becomes a vector so that
$$\mathbf{v} = \omega\times\mathbf{r}$$
where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector to the object and $\mathbf{v}$ is the instantaneous tangential velocity.

So is it possible to chose any physical quantity to be vectorial?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector

Answer (score 0):

No. Not every physical quantity can be a vector. In order for a quantity to be a vector, it must have suitable transformation properties, particularly under the transformation of rotation. At any rate there are many quantities of physical interest that are not vectors, e.g. scalars such as potential a potential energy function, and pseudovectors such as those given by vector cross products. There are also quantities of physical interest that are more general than vectors but share their rotational transformation properties, these are known as tensors.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure there is a detailed mathematical definition, to the typical physicist a quantity is a vector if it adds like like a vector. Observations reveals that velocities, forces, etc add like vectors and so we regard them as vectors.

But there are plenty of properties that do not add like vectors, for example mass and charge. Masses and charges just add like ordinary numbers, and that makes them scalars not vectors.

Answer (score 0):

We don't arbitrarily choose whether something is a Scalar or Vector, it depends on how the quantity behaves under coordinate transformations, not just on convenience.

Below are two examples:

- As you stated, Force and Momentum are vectors. This is because they
  change under coordinate transformations, following to the laws of
  vector transformation.
- The classic example when learning about scalar quantities is Mass.
  Mass is clearly a scalar, since it is invariant to coordinate
  transformations

ω is not a classic polar vector rather is is a psuedovector, aka axial vector.
Psuedovectors are quantities that often behave like vectors, but unlike the classic polar vector, their directions do not conform to when under a rigid transformation. A classic polar vector is transformed into its negative if the coordinate axis are inverted, while a psuedovector would be invariant under the afforemention transforation.